# where can I download cycles as an addon and why does blender not run?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, add-on, installation

I don't know why but the newer versions of Blender don't run on my PC(I have an AMD radeon graphics - 1GB), but the newer versions of cycles have seemed to improve a lot, like giving a pre-made materials to smokes. So, I wanted to try this, since blender doesn't run I wanted to know if I could download cycles as an addon?
Plus, if there are any suggestions regarding how can I get newer versions of blender to run in my PC, please mention them as well, because I'm so confused as it meets all the requirements that Blender's site mention I should to run the newer versions in my PC. My machine has an i5-4200U CPU @ 1.60GHz, RAM is 4.00GB and is a 64-bit operating system with an AMD RADEON 1GB graphics card.
details from the caps viewer:
[image]

[image]

first I go through the install process:
[image]

Then blender install all fine:
[image]

and when I finally hit the blender icon it just crashes without even opening,it shows this:
[image]

Plus I'm using windows 7(ultimate).

Comment: that can be due to this "Blender now requires OpenGL 2.1 minimum" https://www.blender.org/features/2-77/ (I mean for 'Blender don't run on my PC')

Comment: I don't think that you can download Cycles as an addon. If there would be an addon, it still doesn't mean that the most recent version will run with an outdated blender version. In regards to helpful information you might want to consider revealing not only your hardware but also your OS, its version and maybe the GPU itself. There are a lot of 1GB Radeons out there, you know...

Comment: @lemon, caps viwer(from geeks3d) says I have: OpenGL 4.2 (AMD Radeon HD 8670M with 246 ext.)

Comment: @metaphor_set, I don't have a lot of knowledge on hardware, but the details I could get I have updated. Perhaps you might have any idea?

Comment: Now we are going into the right direction ;-) The Screenshot tells us at least the GPU (Radeon HD 8670M and OpenGL 4.2) which should be fine at least for small scenes. However, there is still some information missing. I can guess that you are using Windows, but then I still don't know which version. 7/8/8.1/10? So many versions to choose from...
"Blender dosen't run" is also no sufficient description. What happens _exactly_ when you start the actual Blender version on your Computer? Please change your question and provide enough information for us to give good answers. Thanks.

Comment: @metaphor_set, I uploaded all the information that I could. Plus, in the last screen shot the theme just changed to classic,(I had to render the frame, since it only took a fraction of a second), so that you don't get confused.

Comment: Try using blender without the installer. Download the standalone zip version and run that.

Comment: @cegaton, I tried the zip version as well , but the result is the same.

Comment: Maybe we are close. Your second screenshot was taken from the System Information Window. Above that region of your screenshot there should be a line that says "Service Pack 1". Like this: http://imgur.com/a/81653

Comment: Oh, and it seems that your Graphics Driver is quite old. Since it's an AMD GPU go to http://support.amd.com/en-us/download and try to install a new one.

Comment: @metaphor_set, thanks a lot! I'll try that and post a reply

Comment: I download the exe file and it says it is incompatile with the version of windows i'm using

Comment: What's with the Service Pack 1 I mentioned above?

Comment: Service Pack 1? I actually don't see it. Though I actually downloaded the utility from the support site and tried the auto detection. It recommended the radeon crimson 16.7 setup (it said so but I don't know what it is), and I don't know (I thought It should had been a .dll file) but I tried running that and it said the above message. Do you have any particular recommendation instead

Comment: I strongly suggest that you update your Windows installation. You probably have deactivated Windows Updates. You should also install Windows 7 Service Pack 1, which you get from the Microsoft homepage. You might visit someone with a little more PC knowledge for that.

Answer (score 2):

Cycles cannot be downloaded as an add-on and installed in an older version of Blender - it's too tightly integrated for that.

In case of future googlers coming across this question, Cycles can be used [standalone](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Source/Render/Cycles/Standalone), but that's not really related to your problem.

If you believe blender should be able to run on your computer (your specific graphics card supports OpenGL 2.1, google the model name), then you should [report a bug](http://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/create/?project=2&type=Bug) and let the developers help you find out what's wrong. When describing your problem, be very specific about what's wrong, what error messages there are, your hardware, etc.